# Convergence in distribution of $n \cdot \inf(X_1, ..., X_n)$

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables.

Let's suppose that $X_1$ follows a uniform distribution on [0, 1]. Does $n \cdot \inf(X_1, ..., X_n)$ converge in distribution? If yes, how can this be proved?

Additionnally, I'm given that $\forall a < x < b, \ \mathbb P(X_1 \geq x) < 1$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What about finding the CDF of $n\min_i X_i$?

Comment: I assume you mean $0\leq a<x<b \leq 1.$ You could look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1493441

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. They helped a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y_{n}=n\cdot inf\left\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\right\}$ then

$$
1-F_{Y_n}(y)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-F_{X_{n}}(y/n)\right)\implies F_{Y_n}(y)=1-(1-y/n)^n
$$

Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$

$$
F_Y(y)=1-e^{-y}
$$
Si it converges in distribution to an exponential