# How can I find the CDF and show convergence of $n \cdot \min\{X_1,X_2,... \}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be independent r.v. and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Let $n\in\mathbb N$.

How can I determine the cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F_n$ of the random variables $n \min\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n \}$ and to what CDF does $F_n$ converge for $n \to \infty$?

---

**My attempt:** I wasn't sure how to really start because the factor "$n$" is making things difficult so I have a few questions upfront:

1. When dealing with problems like this, is my strategy to find the probability density function (PDF) first and only then try to figure out the CDF or can I go straight to determining the CDF?
2. What is the correct notation for the CDF? I am used to seeing $F_X(x)$=$P(X\le x)$ which makes sense to me since it specifies the distribution "$X$" and the value "$x$". Is $F_n$ just an equivalent notation?

For the CDF my guess would be:

$$F_n=\begin{cases}0 & \text{for} & x <0 \\
? & \text{for} & 0 \le x\le 1 \\ ? & \text{for} & x>1\end{cases}  $$

I just don't know how to deal with the $n$ factor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence in distribution of $n \cdot \inf(X_1, ..., X_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164988/convergence-in-distribution-of-n-cdot-infx-1-x-n)

Comment: @tommik Yes it sort of does but doesn't answer my soft questions. Also, at first glance Ilya's answer makes a bit more sense to me but thanks a lot for the link :)

Comment: after applying the definition of min, the limit you have to calculate is the same of this example, now posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4167986/showing-a-cdf-converges-in-distribution-to-and-exponential-distribution

Comment: Don't use the title "Attempt* when all you actually do is avoid telling us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that $\min(X_i, i \in I) > t$ if and only if $X_i > t$ for all $i\in I$. That's why it is first suggested to find the CDF:
$$
\begin{align}
\Bbb P(n\cdot \min(X_i, i\leq n) \leq t) 
&= 1 -\Bbb P(n\cdot \min(X_i, i\leq n) > t)
\\ 
&= 1 - \Bbb P\left(X_i > \frac tn, i\leq n\right) 
\\
&= 1 - \prod_{i = 1}^n \Bbb P\left(X_i> \frac tn\right)
\end{align}
$$
due to the independence of $X_i$. Just tell me if you can figure out the rest by yourself.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: you are right! my bad. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the edit. I was trying to figure out the first answer but I was confused and now it makes much more sense. Thanks!