# Showing a CDF converges in distribution to an exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Context: $X_{i} \sim UNIF(0,\theta)$ and $U_{n} = (n+1)X_{1:n}$

I found the CDF: $P[U_{n} < x] = 1 - [1 - \frac{x}{\theta(n+1)}]^{n}$.

Now I must show that when $n$ tends to infinity $U_{n}$ converges in distribution to an exponential distribution.

I know the CDF of an exponential distribution is as follows: $1 - e^{-x/\theta}$  when $X \sim EXP(\theta)$.

I guess I must use some known limits and the only one I can think of is $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac{c}{n})^{nb} = e^{cb}$. This limit was also given in our text book. Nonetheless I couldn't figure this one out. Can someone help me?

Comment: Yes, you use that particular expression for getting the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you indicate $X_{1:n}$ as $X_{(1)}=\min_i(X_i)$, your CDF is the following

$$F_{U_n}(u)=1-\left[ 1-\frac{u}{(n+1)\theta} \right]^n=1-L$$

$$L=\left\{\left[ 1+\frac{\frac{-u}{\theta}}{n+1} \right]^\frac{n}{\frac{-u}{\theta}}\right\}^{\frac{-u}{\theta}}\approx\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^t\right]^{\frac{-u}{\theta}}\xrightarrow{t \to \infty}e^{-u/\theta}$$

Thus your CDF converges to

$$F_U(u)=1-e^{-u/\theta}$$

... as expected

Comment: Thank you very much!